# df -h results different than VGdisplay / LVdisplay

Tags: lvm, data, pv

Im trying to remove the added disk to the VM, as the disk space is not needed anymore.
However, it looks to be that the VM has in the VG almost all the data used what is available there.

However, i've managed to resize the zoneminder--vg to 6G almost from 1,5TB
with `resiz2fs` but lvdisplay says differently.

Here is the output of some commands.

```
root@zoneminder:~# lvs
  LV     VG            Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log  Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   zoneminder-vg -wi-ao----   1.52t
  swap_1 zoneminder-vg -wi-ao---- 976.00m
root@zoneminder:~# pvs
  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  900.00g     0
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  699.52g 46.57g
root@zoneminder:~# vgs
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  zoneminder-vg   2   2   0 wz--n- 1.56t 46.57g
```

DF - H

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.6G  8.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root  5.6G  4.9G  431M  92% /
tmpfs                            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                        472M  108M  340M  25% /boot
tmpfs                            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

pvdisplay

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               zoneminder-vg
  PV Size               699.52 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              179077
  Free PE               11922
  Allocated PE          167155
  PV UUID               SVGqoc-SQ42-tDzp-Qc7H-n90f-1g9n-x0eLWe

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               zoneminder-vg
  PV Size               900.00 GiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              230400
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          230400
  PV UUID               Cdanv0-2pLJ-Yp2n-3zsl-JvjH-72QS-Ciwhaj
```

lvdisplay

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/zoneminder-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                zoneminder-vg
  LV UUID                poThtY-v96W-e2Ai-nan7-ckqn-aeBm-T0Kqji
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time zoneminder, 2018-08-01 22:22:13 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.52 TiB
  Current LE             397311
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/zoneminder-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                zoneminder-vg
  LV UUID                SXQ36r-5Kum-Z3Wa-m9DE-CBVb-h9Wx-kmctKT
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time zoneminder, 2018-08-01 22:22:13 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                976.00 MiB
  Current LE             244
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

vgdisplay

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               zoneminder-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               1.56 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              409477

  Alloc PE / Size       397555 / 1.52 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       11922 / 46.57 GiB

  VG UUID               lTo8U0-dIL9-Yye3-RVYk-rJu6-w6WQ-zIpL8f
```

How can i make the /dev/sda3 remove without hitting any data on the LVM?
And then rebuilt the VGroup back again, to 100G or something?

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.6 TiB, 1717986918400 bytes, 3355443200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x21880f4a

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     999423     997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          1001470 1468004351 1467002882 699.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       1468004352 3355443199 1887438848   900G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5          1001472 1468004351 1467002880 699.5G 8e Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root: 1.5 TiB, 1666443116544 bytes, 3254771712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
root@zoneminder:~#
```

Update#1:

@telcoM : Thank you for you kind and detailed answer
All the actions mentioned by you where done.
I came across also that the data was ofcourse spread all over the disk, so I had to physically move the data also:

```
root@zoneminder:~# pvresize --setphysicalvolume 101G -v /dev/sda5
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
    Archiving volume group "zoneminder-vg" metadata (seqno 9).
    /dev/sda5: Pretending size is 211812352 not 1467002880 sectors.
    Resizing volume "/dev/sda5" to 211812352 sectors.
    Resizing physical volume /dev/sda5 from 0 to 25855 extents.
  /dev/sda5: cannot resize to 25855 extents as later ones are allocated.
  0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized


root@zoneminder:~# pvs -v --segments /dev/sda5
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start  SSize  LV     Start Type   PE Ranges
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  699.52g 598.57g      0  25600 root       0 linear /dev/sda5:0-25599
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  699.52g 598.57g  25600 141311            0 free
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  699.52g 598.57g 166911    244 swap_1     0 linear /dev/sda5:166911-167154
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  699.52g 598.57g 167155  11922            0 free

root@zoneminder:~# sudo pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/sda5:166911-167154 /dev/sda5:25601-25845
  /dev/sda5: Moved: 0.4%
  /dev/sda5: Moved: 100.0%

root@zoneminder:~# pvresize --setphysicalvolume 101G -v /dev/sda5
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
    Archiving volume group "zoneminder-vg" metadata (seqno 12).
    /dev/sda5: Pretending size is 211812352 not 1467002880 sectors.
    Resizing volume "/dev/sda5" to 211812352 sectors.
    Resizing physical volume /dev/sda5 from 0 to 25855 extents.
    Updating physical volume "/dev/sda5"
    Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/zoneminder-vg" (seqno 13).
  Physical volume "/dev/sda5" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

root@zoneminder:~# pvs -v --segments /dev/sda5
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  Start SSize LV     Start Type   PE Ranges
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  101.00g 44.00m     0 25600 root       0 linear /dev/sda5:0-25599
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  101.00g 44.00m 25600     1            0 free
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  101.00g 44.00m 25601   244 swap_1     0 linear /dev/sda5:25601-25844
  /dev/sda5  zoneminder-vg lvm2 a--  101.00g 44.00m 25845    10            0 free
```

Actually what I'm trying to achieve is the following (post #18):
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2723540#2723540

I'm now stuck at that `/dev/sda3` has not been removed, still seeing in `fdisk -l` and the size of `/dev/sda5` is still 700G.

```
root@zoneminder:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 1.6 TiB, 1717986918400 bytes, 3355443200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x21880f4a

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     999423     997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          1001470 1468004351 1467002882 699.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       1468004352 3355443199 1887438848   900G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5          1001472 1468004351 1467002880 699.5G 8e Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

UPDATE #2:

I've managed via an LIVE-CD to use GPARTED and PARTED to remove the disk and resize the `/dev/sda2` wherein also `/dev/sda5` is with the LV(M)

Because of the snapshots in ESXi I've made, I need to redo all the steps again. Because the nesteling of the vmdk's are a bit nasty as it seems to be.

It takes a while untill the orignal VM has been copied (1,6TB). After this I will do a full dump of all the steps such that in the future, someone else can use it also.

Answer (score 1):

Great, you've successfully shrunk the *filesystem* inside the root LV.

The next step is to shrink the LV to match the new size of the filesystem. For the sake of safety, you may want to leave a bit of slack, as accidentally cutting off too much would be a far worse problem.

Filesystem shrinking operations are always bit more risky than extensions, especially if you are not yet quite familiar with them. So backup anything you might need, just in case something goes wrong.

Then use `tune2fs -l` to get the exact block count from the filesystem:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root | grep "Block "
Block count:          NNNNNNNNN
Block size:           XXXX
```

Multiply these two numbers together to get the exact size of the filesystem, then divide by 1024 to get binary kilobytes, and again to get binary megabytes. Add one to protect against rounding errors:

```
expr NNNNNNNNN \* XXXX / 1024 / 1024 + 1
SSSSSS
```

Now, shrink the LV:

```
lvreduce -L SSSSSS /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root
```

Now you should have plenty of free space in your Zoneminder VG. Use the `pvs` to confirm whether `/dev/sda3` is now completely unused or not:

If, in the `pvs` output, the PFree value is not equal to PSize for `/dev/sda3`, there are still some parts of the root LV on that PV, and you'll need to move them out of there. `pvmove` can easily do that. If `/dev/sda3` is now completely fbree, you can skip this step.

```
pvmove /dev/sda3
```

This essentially says "make `sda3` empty by moving all the LV data that's still in ot to other PVs belonging to this same VG."

`pvmove` works by mirroring a piece of the data to be moved to its new location, then "removing the mirror" from the old side. So if `pvmove` gets interrupted by a system crash, it's not catastrophic. Just run `pvmove` with no parameters to continue from where it was.

Now, the `sda3` PV should be completely empty. Remove it from the VG:

```
vgreduce zoneminder-vg /dev/sda3
```

At this point, `/dev/sda3` will be an unattached, completely free LVM PV. You can wipe the PVID from it if you wish:

```
pvremove /dev/sda3
```

Now you'll be free to reuse the `/dev/sda3` partition any way you like.
(If you plan to do something that causes the partition to be overwritten anyway, the `pvremove` command won't be strictly necessary.)

Now, if you want to extend the root LV to 100 GiB, here are the steps:

```
lvextend -L 100G /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/zoneminder--vg-root
```

And you're done.

Note that I didn't say "unmount the filesystem" or "reboot the system" at any point here. **It isn't necessary.**

Comment: thank you!! see my updated question please

Comment: Think of it as layers: at the bottom, there is the physical disk. On top of it, there is the partitioning layer, then inside the partition, there is the LVM layer on top of the partition layer. And the filesystem is on top of LVM. You've now successfully manipulated the filesystem and LVM layers to make `sda3` empty and unused; now you're free to use `fdisk` or other partitioning tool to either change the type of the partition to something else, or to delete the entire partition and possibly put something else in its place.

Comment: Since `sda3` is physically located after `sda5` on the disk, you can now just delete it. And as you also resized the `sda5` PV to 101G, you can also shrink that partition to 101G (or preferably to slightly more than that, to account for rounding errors). Once that's successfully done, you should also resize `sda2` as the extended partition acts as an "envelope" for the "logical" partitions (sda5 and above). Then you can tell VMware to take away the extra disk space.

Comment: You know after a lot of reading there is still no perception of how it is being built. I've come to see more and more, with practising it myself and your key-words has helped me with getting further to the finish line :)

Answer (score 0):

The LVM system has no idea of how you use your logical volumes. Even if you reduces the filesystem that you use in your LV, it does not change the size of the LV, nor the free space in your VG and PV (all space allocated to a LV is considered in use).

If you reduced you filesystem, you can reduce your LV with the `lvreduce` command, but you should be extra careful not to reduce it to small to fit your filesystem, or you may lose some data.

Once you have reduced your logical volume, you may move the used space from one PV to another one, with the `pvmove` command, and then remove the PV from the VG with the `vgreduce` command.